# Plotting stereonets in R

Tags: geology, structural-geology, data-analysis, software

Is there a package for R to plot Schmidt nets, like it is done in geology?

So far, I only know software like Stereonet. However I think it would make a lot of sense to handle these data in R, to have so much more possibilities in calculations and statistics.

Comment: Schmidt nets are not familiar to me. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt_net) it is a method to construct a Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection. [This tutorial on GMT](http://www-k12.atmos.washington.edu/~ovens/nobackup/gmt/doc/html/GMT_Docs/node72.html) states that the a Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection is also known as equal-area (Schmidt) stereonet. The question [R mapproj lambert-azimuthal equal area projection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725458/r-mapproj-lambert-azimuthal-equal-area-projection) might provide an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the [RockFab package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RockFab/). I am not a structural geologist but I use other R packages for geological endevours.

[Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RockFab/RockFab.pdf).

Comment: The function `StereoWeb` in the `RockFab` package might be appropriate.

Comment: It took some time to get it running, because it requires EBImage, which is not available in the CRAN repository, but at least it's exacly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You can install EBImage by following the instructions here: https://github.com/aoles/EBImage

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `net` function in the [RFOC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RFOC) package